# Add image contact in address book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, contacts

how can i use `kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail` or something else to set an **image to a contact** in address book???

I want use a `/resources` file.

Now i use

```
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, @"+39-02-1234567", kABWorkLabel, NULL);
```

to set a value in address book.

An image seems to be the same behavior, but what type need use?

```
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, ?????, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail, NULL);
```

Thanks
A

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ouch...
resolved!

```
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"];
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(im);
ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
```

[>>> objective-c-add-contact-contacts-list](http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2011/01/objective-c-add-contact-contacts-list/)

thanks all.